# access individual elements from a list of pow and symbol sympy python

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to access individual elements in a long list of symbols, and one of pow types generated using Sympy, here is how the come out in the console:

```
x00
x01
x10
x11
x00
x10
x20
x00
x01
x02
x03
x00
x01
x10
x02
x11
x12
x00
x01
x10
x11
x20
x21
x00
x10
x20
x30
```

The pow is generated using

```
   A = (ymat[0])**(nvec[0]-mvec[0])             #alpha term: mu^(n-k)
            for nv in range (1, nvariables):
                A = A* (ymat[nv]**(nvec[nv]-mvec[nv]))
```

And the symbols using:

```
        mstr = str(mvec[0])                          #beta term: x^k
        for mm in range(1, len(mvec)):
            mstr = mstr + str(mvec[mm])
        B = Symbol('x'+mstr)
```

I've tried using indexation in python such as A[1] but I get error message:

```
TypeError: 'Symbol' object does not support indexing
```

or

```
TypeError: 'Pow' object does not support indexing
```

Does anyone know how I could access individual elements such as (1x00)

Comment: where does the list of symbols come from. I.e a functional call which is returns a generator? A file? etc...

Comment: HennyH The symbols are generated by a function that takes input from elsewhere, I can post that code. 
@root couldn't think of anything else to call it

Comment: Please give full working code to reproduce your issue. I have no idea what `ymat`, `nvec`, and so on are.

Answer (score 0):

Symbols compare equal by name (and also by assumptions, but it doesn't look like you are using those), so you could just recreate the same Symbol by making one with the same name.  So if you want `x00`, just create `Symbol('x00')` again, and it will give you the same thing.

Comment: I just tried this and it printed the list but with (x00) appended to every  element. What do you mean by 'by assumptions'?

Comment: Assumptions are things like `real=True` that you might add when creating a Symbol.